# Django downloading file:UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, django

I use Django 1.11 to download file.This is my function.

```
def file_downloading(request, filename):
    path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'/'
    the_file_name = path+filename
    f_name = filename.split('/')[len(filename.split('/'))-1]
    wrapper = FileWrapper(open(the_file_name, "r"))
    content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(the_file_name)[0]
    response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type=content_type)
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(path) 
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s f_name 
    return response`
```

But I got a `UnicodeDecodeError` when I was trying to download .pdf file.Actually it only works when the file is .txt . When I change the wrapper to `open("file_name","rb")`,the file can be downloaded, but it can't be opened.How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: the_file_name, "w", try this

Comment: Try `wrapper = open(the_file_name, "rb")`, means remove FileWrapper

Comment: It is much better to use `os.path.join` to construct filesystem paths instead of string concatentation. Such code is more portable and is easier to read.

Comment: `wrapper = open(the_file_name, "rb")` It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's HttpResponse class is most suitable for a text based response (html page, txt file, etc.). The [documentation for the class constructor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.__init__) explains:

> content should be an iterator or a string. If it’s an iterator, it should return strings, and those strings will be joined together to form the content of the response. If it is not an iterator or a string, it will be converted to a string when accessed.

You UnicodeDecodeError is probably raised when the `content` is converted to a string. If you want to return a PDF file, the file content is binary data, so it is not intended to be converted to string.

You may use the [FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects) class instead. It inherits from StreamingHttpResponse, and so have a different APi than HttpResponse, but it will probably works better to return a binary file (like a PDF).

Comment: I use `FileResponse` and return error code in my browsers...Could u please give a specific example about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an encoding to the file that you are opening like this:

```
open(the_file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 11: invalid start byte I forgot to put up this information...I 've tried this way...But anyway thanks for help.